# Does creating a new NFT collection require a contract for it?

Tags: contract-development, nft

To create my own NFT collection, will I have to create **a smart contract for it** too? Or could it be done without one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in order to create an NFT collection you have to create a smart contract that inherits the ERC721 standard and deploy it.

If your NFT contract is meant to be fairly standard I suggest that you use Open Zepellin's contract wizard for ERC721 to develop the contract https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard

Answer (score 1):

There are also services that allow you to mint NFTs within their platform for free. This is called lazy minting and can be found at Opensea.

However these NFTs don't have much value as they are not considered the "real" NFTs. Read more about it [here](https://opensea.io/blog/announcements/introducing-the-collection-manager/).